# Whatsapp media file name convert Android to IOS

Tags: android, ios, database, naming-conventions, whatsapp

If I have my WhatsApp database (msgstore.db) and I want to convert the names of the media files from the way they are called in Android for example
IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg

To the way they are called on IOS in the WhatsApp application

For example the file `IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg` will become `384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg`

I have not been able to research how WhatsApp gives the names to the files in an IOS operating system

There are many programs that transfer WhatsApp from Android to iPhone and they know how to change the name of the file and also to return it back, i.e. from
`384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg` back to
`IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg` 
How do they do it? What determines the name of the file?

What I tried to do was to find a common denominator between the WhatsApp database in ios (ChatStorage.sqlite) and the database in Android (msgstore.db)

I was able to notice that regarding the size of the media, the exact date, a link to download the file (in an encrypted format ~ .enc), a unique value for the message stored in ZSTANZAID, in addition the hash ID of the message is a common part

None of these made me succeed in figuring out how to rename media files from Android to iPhone

Comment: Is there anyone who can explain this?

Answer (score 1):

You should'nt be able to convert "384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg" back to "IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg". WhatsApp has hashed the original file name with SHA256 to avoid collosions on their server's, therefore you can't convert a hash back to his original value.

Comment: interesting. Since companies that make computer software for transferring between iPhone and Android and vice versa (like Backuptrans) are able to perform this conversion without a problem, from a check I made on my WhatsApp database I could not find out how they manage to do it

Comment: @Aviv Mostlikely there is a lookup table on the server/client with the hash as its key and the original file name as value.

Comment: I couldn't find anything like this in the ChatStorage.sqlite or in msgstore.db


just to clarify my intention to "original file name":
When an X file is sent/received from the Whatsapp application on Android it is saved as
IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg

On the other hand,on the iPhone, it is saved as
384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg

Where 
384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg
and 
IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg  
exactly the same file

It's just not clear how to turn IMG-20201026-WA0000.jpg into 384cf8623831c156d21ec1e96caebc6c.jpg
  and vice versa